# Trying to identify a comic book about something called the Stark Islands

Tags: marvel

I am having a hard time recollecting the name of a comic book. I guess it was released in 2006. It was about some Stark Islands. All I remember properly is that it had a kid who was a rockstar and there was a mentioning of his album named "**Alien Ant Asylum**".

Probably that kid was also a scientist working on "*Transmutation of energy in higher dimensions*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing the alternate Harry Pym (AKA Ant-Man) depicted in the [Marvel Mangaverse](http://marvel.wikia.com/Henry_Pym_%28Earth-2301%29) comic series. This character appeared in only [4 comics](http://marvel.wikia.com/Category:Henry_Pym_(Earth-2301)/Appearances) set on 'Earth 2301'.

The Marvel Wiki description mentions both the Stark Islands and Pym's album.

> ***Hank was one of the people Toni Stark invited to Stark Island** in order to unveil the Negative Zone powered reactor she had Bruce Banner build.*
>
> *He later helps the forces of Stark Island hold off the Atlantean Invasion whilst trying to stabilize the reactor.*
>
> ***This version of Hank Pym released an album called 'Alien-Ant Asylum'**, which Bruce Banner claimed to be a fan of.*

[image]

Comment: I guess ,this is the comics I was talking about. I remember that comics was having some obscene pictures featuring a woman on shower and I ,hailing from a prudish had a hard time trying to hide that book . But I doubt if marvel have any comics with such content.

Comment: @SheldonKripke - If this turned out to be the right comic, could you click the "accepted" button. Cheers.

Comment: Yes this is the comics . But do you have the exact name of this comics ?

Comment: @SheldonKripke - They're listed [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Henry_Pym_(Earth-2301)/Appearances). You've not given enough info to narrow it down to a specific issue out of the four that it could be.

Comment: In a kind of embarrassing  manner the only other clue I remember is the picture of a naked beautiful woman taking a shower inside a closed glass chamber and her servant robot watching her and her kid playing outside . she was getting ready for some conference .

Comment: In conference one of the attendees speak of her as being very generous and I am not sure of what name do they use for her . However the robot had some kind of emotion mechanism and he feels embarrassed to watch her naked and utters something like " I am being flattered , I was just created for your service "